# How to create a mixed mode CLR .NET DLL that uses AFX libraries?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, clr, afx

I am trying to create a mixed mode (managed and unmanaged) C++ DLL with CLR option and I require the use of AFX library. So I included "afxwin.h" in a file (which uses GL/gl.h).
However I run into compile errors no matter what I do and I have tried every option in the project settings to fix them, but no use.

A. When I compile with CLR option I see this error (when it compiles the file which includes afwin.h):

1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

B. When I compile with _AFXDLL defined in stdafx.cpp or enabling "Use MFC in a shared DLL", to address the error in A, I see these and whole bunch of other errors in the same file:

1>  _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxanimationcontroller.h(46): error C2059: syntax error : '-'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxanimationcontroller.h(60): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxanimationcontroller.h(60): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxanimationcontroller.h(61): error C2059: syntax error : 'public'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxanimationcontroller.h(65): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxanimationcontroller.h(65): error C2589: '-' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxanimationcontroller.h(65): error C2059: syntax error : '::'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxanimationcontroller.h(67): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? I am using VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MFC option afterwards to "Use MFC in a shared DLL" is not that straightforward, there are other options you may need to change.

The easiest way is to create a new dummy MFC project with the wizard and compare the project properties of the two projects.

Re CLR, what works for me is to place all managed C++ code in one or two sources and turn on /CLR only for those sources instead of the whole project.

Comment: Thanks Edward. I was able to figure out the fix similar to what you mentioned. In fact, I did have a handy full-fledged MFC project whose settings and files I compared. All I had to do was add several other afxwin related files into my stdafx.h file and voila it fixed the compile issues!

Comment: nice you to have solved it by you and your self. how about after sharing your excitement with the World, to share also and solution ;)